# VB.Net Class/Method improvement

Tags: vb.net, class

I have made a class that I am using for a SQL Prepared Statement Function. The class is

```
Public Class _SQLParameter
    Public Name As String
    Public Length As Int16
    Public Value As Object
End Class
```

I have this code to create the parameter

```
Public Function MakeMyParameter(ByVal strName As String, ByVal intLength As Integer, ByVal objValue As Object) As _SQLParameter
    Dim param As New _SQLParameter
    param.Name = strName
    param.Length = intLength
    param.Value = objValue
    Return param
End Function
```

I then use this code to pass variables to another function to Insert Data to a SQL database.

```
    Dim MyDatabaseName as "MyDatabase"
    Dim MyTableName as "Password"
    Dim MyVariableList As New List(Of _SQLParameter)
    MyVariableList.Add(MakeMyParameter("Password",0,varbytePassword))
    MyVariableList.Add(MakeMyParameter("DateTimeChanged",0,DateTime.Now()))
    _SQLPreparedInsertStatement(MyDatabaseName, MyTableName, MyVariableList)
```

My function then uses the database name, table name and passed list variable to create the prepared statement and execute the NonQuery. This work well.

All of the code works but I want to know how to improve my code because it seems horrible to me. I am not an expert in .NET but can do enough to get by. If you can give me some suggestions on how to improve it would be fantastic.

Thanks

Edit....

I use this sub routine to create the Prepared Statement and execute it. I have made it so I can re-use it for any INSERT statement I have.

```
Public Sub _SQLPreparedInsertStatement(ByVal _SQLDatabaseName As String, ByVal _SQLTableName As String, _SQLParameters As List(Of _SQLParameter))
    Dim _ColumnNames As String = ""
    Dim _Parameters As String = ""

    Dim _SQLInsertCommand As New SqlCommand()
    _SQLInsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text


    Try
        Using _SQLConnection As New SqlConnection(_varstrSQLLocalDBConnectionString)
            Try
                _SQLConnection.Open()
                _SQLInsertCommand.Connection = _SQLConnection
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Error - " & ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try

            For Each param As _SQLParameter In _SQLParameters
                _ColumnNames = _ColumnNames & param.Name & ","
                _Parameters = _Parameters & "@" & param.Name & ","
                If TypeOf param.Value Is Byte() Then
                    _SQLInsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@" & param.Name, SqlDbType.VarBinary, param.Length).Value = param.Value
                ElseIf TypeOf param.Value Is String Then
                    _SQLInsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@" & param.Name, SqlDbType.VarChar, param.Length).Value = param.Value
                ElseIf TypeOf param.Value Is Integer Then
                    _SQLInsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@" & param.Name, SqlDbType.Int, param.Length).Value = param.Value
                ElseIf TypeOf param.Value Is DateTime Then
                    _SQLInsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@" & param.Name, SqlDbType.DateTime, 0).Value = param.Value
                End If
            Next
            'remove comma from the end of the variables
            _ColumnNames = _ColumnNames.TrimEnd(",")
            _Parameters = _Parameters.TrimEnd(",")

            Try
                _SQLInsertCommand.CommandText = "USE " & _SQLDatabaseName & "; INSERT INTO " & _SQLTableName & " (" & _ColumnNames & ") VALUES (" & _Parameters & ")"

                _SQLInsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred executing a SQL command - " & ex.Message & Environment.NewLine & "Query - " & _SQLInsertCommand.CommandText, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Some Error. Most unexpected")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess it's not really clear *why* you have this code in the first place, since .NET already provides this functionality.

Comment: If you use some of the overloads available, you can create and add a parameter directly without a helper class: `cmd.Parameters.Add(param, dbType, size).Value = typedValue`.  The "helper"  class becomes more work than doing it directly.

Comment: `this code to ... Insert Data`  For single tables, you can configure the DataAdapter to "remember" the INSERT, SELECT, DELETE and UPDATE commands and simple issue `Update`s on the underlying datatable.  A fully configured DA has many other advantages and features as well

Comment: I have added another module to try to explain the purpose of the code more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

.NET already does this for you.  Here is a complete example of the concepts you're looking for..

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Using connection As New SqlConnection("Server=SERVERNAME;Database=DATABASENAME;uid=USERNAME;pwd=PASSWORD")
            connection.Open()
            Using cmd As SqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand
                With cmd
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .CommandText = "UPDATE SomeTable SET SomeField=@NewValue WHERE SomeField=@OldValue"
                    With .Parameters
                        .AddWithValue("@OldValue", "smith")
                        .AddWithValue("@NewValue", "jones")
                    End With
                    .ExecuteNonQuery()
                End With
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I understand that this is possible and I use it already. I have tried to write a single function so I can re-use it for different INSERT statements without having to re-write a subroutine for each variation. See reply below

Comment: Having maintained legacy systems with code similar to what you are proposing, I can tell you that it is a maintenance nightmare.  I strongly encourage you to use the established patterns for such things.  Tying to drive all of your database square pegs through this single round hole is a decision that you will regret.